# Validator: No space between attributes

Tags: html-validation

Подскажите, на что ругается валидатор:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а у Вас <!DOCTYPE html> указан? или как-то иначе?

Comment: @humster_spb да, именно так

Comment: странно, вот здесь пишут, что должно работать: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566516/itemtype-attribute-error-in-validate

Comment: ещё пишут, что может быть у Вас где-то между атрибутами есть точка с запятой: https://wpnew.ru/raskrutka-bloga/seo_optimizaciya/validator-html.html#no-space

Comment: странно, вроде ж нет лишних символов

Comment: тогда очевидно проблема в xmlns - пишут, что в html5 эту всю бороду указывать не надо: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563846/does-html-5-need-html-xmlns-http-www-w3-org-1999-xhtml/14563918#14563918

Comment: да, действительно, спасибо большое!